# DataWeave groupBy with maxBy

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I'm a bit of a DataWeave newb. I'm trying to grab the latest deduction records for a user but also group by the type in the array. This is the data I have to work with:

```
"users": [
    {
        "employeeId": "123456",
        "lastName": "smith",
        "firstName": "joe ",
        "deductions": [
            {
                "deductionType": "ABC",
                "Amt": 1000,
                "StartDate": "2001-01-02T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "deductionType": "ABC",
                "Amt": 1000,
                "StartDate": "2019-01-02T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "deductionType": "ABC",
                "Amt": 1000,
                "StartDate": "2016-01-02T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "deductionType": "DCA",
                "Amt": 4000,
                "StartDate": "2019-11-02T00:00:00",
            }
        ]
    }
```

I've tried to go with a similar solution posted on: [Dataweave 2.0 maxBy and filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57279351/dataweave-2-0-maxby-and-filter)
 But that doesn't seem to work as I'm getting a null payload.

The end result should look like this:

```
    "users": [
    {
        "employeeId": "123456",
        "lastName": "smith",
        "firstName": "joe ",
        "deductions": [
            {
                "deductionType": "ABC",
                "Amt": 1000,
                "StartDate": "2019-01-02T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "deductionType": "DCA",
                "Amt": 4000,
                "StartDate": "2019-11-02T00:00:00",
            }
        ]
```

My current try to the solution is:

```
    payload.users map {($),
               deductions: (($.deductions groupBy $.deductionType) mapObject (value, key) -> 
                            {(key) : (value maxBy $.benefitStartDate)}) pluck (value) -> value
```

}

But this isn't working either.

Comment: I am trying to understand what are the criteria for removing deductions--it seems you are just keeping the latest one (date-wise); am I correct?

Comment: I'm trying to grab the user and deduction records for that user  grouped by deductionType with the latest start date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{ 
    users: payload.users map {
        ($ - "deductions"),
        deductions: (($.deductions groupBy $.deductionType) pluck $) map {
            ($ maxBy $.StartDate)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It gets me a little closer. Now I'm just getting a null user and not a completely null payload.

Comment: Using your sample input I am able to get the expected end result with the above transformation.  Can you post the result you are now getting?

Comment: I'm only getting:
 output application/java 
---
 {
  users: null
}
 When I step through it in debug.

Comment: I also tried @shortstackstevens solution and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different take to the solution, use the one that performs the better :).
Comments with the algorithm can be seen in the DW expression.
Moreover, I hardcode your sample data in the code so you only need to copy and paste to convince that the DW expression works.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/dw

var data = "users": [
    {
        "employeeId": "123456",
        "lastName": "smith",
        "firstName": "joe ",
        "deductions": [
            {
                "deductionType": "ABC",
                "Amt": 1000,
                "StartDate": "2001-01-02T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "deductionType": "ABC",
                "Amt": 1000,
                "StartDate": "2019-01-02T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "deductionType": "ABC",
                "Amt": 1000,
                "StartDate": "2016-01-02T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "deductionType": "DCA",
                "Amt": 4000,
                "StartDate": "2019-11-02T00:00:00",
            }
        ]
    }
]
---
users: data.users map do {
    // Sort by StartDate, I type casted to a `DateTime` instead of comparing strings
    // Reverse the sorted list such that the latest dates are at the top of the list
    // Finally, get a set out the list where uniqueness is the deductionType
    //   since distinctBy maintains the first element that matches and removes the rest
    //   you know have a list of distinct deductionType with the latest date.       
    var ds = ($.deductions orderBy ($.StartDate as DateTime))[-1 to 0]
              distinctBy (d) -> d.deductionType
    ---
    {
        ($ - "deductions"),
        deductions: ds
    }
}
```

Comment: response looks interesting way,  declaring `var` inside the main body of dataweave `---`, and again using `---`  multiple times. Can i see mule docs related to this example. I'm keen on it.Thanks

Comment: In DW 2.0 @star there is a new way of creating localized declarations with limited scope (aka closures).  Its `do {<declarations> --- <expression> }`.   The page that this feature should be explained is in this page: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/dataweave-variables#example_local_variable.  Unfortunately, it is not explained instead we only have the `using () ()` way which (1) is legacy, (2) should no be used, and (3) is bugged out because it does not limit the scope of the declarations.